# Map website where I can copy a village's name (ex:麻布十番, want text form, not image)

Tags: google-maps, bing-maps

I am preparing an itinerary with Google Maps, and have spot a village on the way where it would be convenient to stay. To look for hosting in that village, I need to copy paste this village's name into a booking search engine.

PROBLEM: The village's name is in Japanese with a complex character I can not read.
The name is in the image. Switching to Google Maps in English gives a transliterated string that is not useful because it collides with hundreds of other places with a different name but same pronunciation.
How to get this **village's name in text form?**

*Note: Most Japanese can not read all villages names, so it would be useful to a bunch of people, not just me.*

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you right-click and choose "What's here?", it should show you an approximation of the address (in text) on the left, including the city's name.  At least this works for me in the U.S. and Mexico, the two places where I travel and use Google Maps for precisely the same thing.